# EF Explicitly loading collection within collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Simple question but from the Entity Framework MSDN examples and other searches I can't see the correct way to do this.

I can explicitly load an EF collection like so:

```
db.Entry(project).Collection(p => p.Reports).Load();
```

But if each report has a list of pages within them that need to load, how do I do it? I figured it was something like:

```
db.Entry(project.Reports).Collection(r => r.Pages).Load();
```

But this won't work, because 'r' is an ICollection of Reports. What is the correct way to load collections within collections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
db.Entry(project).Collection(p => p.Reports)
  .Query()
  .Include(r => r.Pages).Load();
```

As per MSDN, [Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679206(v=vs.113).aspx) ...

> Returns the query that would be used to load this collection from the database. The returned query can be modified

... which means that also `Include` can be applied to it.

Comment: Don't forget `using System.Data.Entity;` if you aren't already. I was getting a syntax error and that was the suggested fix. Works!